# Declare features and target in a pyspark MLlib decision tree classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to train a simple decision tree classifier using `pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree`. I am used to the typical syntax where you declare a model and then explicitly pass a set of features and a target (as separate objects) to its `fit` method.

However, from [the examples I have found](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/mllib-decision-tree.html#classification), it seems that pyspark models only expect the dataset and they somehow determine which columns are features and which column is the target.

I do not know how to tell a `pyspark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree` obect that certain columns in my dataframe are features and that one column is the target. Here's a replicable example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
# Load breast cancer dataset
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

# Save features in X and target in y
X, y = load_breast_cancer()['data'], load_breast_cancer()['target']

# Concatenate X and y into a single pandas dataset
data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['col' + str(i) for i in range(30)]),
                  pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['target'])], axis=1)

# Convert pandas DataFrame to pyspark DataFrame
data = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# Import DT model
from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree

# Declare trained object (how do I tell the model which columns in `data` are features?)
clf = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(data, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                   impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)
```

Which raises the following error:

> An error was encountered: the data should be RDD of LabeledPoint
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line
> 217, in trainClassifier
> impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py",
> line 142, in _train
> assert isinstance(first, LabeledPoint), "the data should be RDD of LabeledPoint" AssertionError: the data should be RDD of LabeledPoint

My question is: how can I pass `data` to `DecisionTree.trainClassifier`?

My guess is that `data` should have some attributes that help the model tell the features from the target.

Comment: why are you reading spark 1.5 docs... Have a look at the latest docs and use spark.ml. mllib is deprecated and relies on RDD which are more tedious to use. Spark ML uses dataframes which you may find easier.

Comment: I did not realize there was a difference between `spark.ml` and `spark.mllib`.